# Excel VBA find webpage link id

Tags: excel, vba

The webpage that I am working with has 60 to 100 menu links on it depending on the users credentials. I use this code to click on the menu link:

```
 Set oapp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
         For i = 0 To 25
         StrName = ""
         On Error Resume Next
         StrName = oapp.Windows(i).Document.URL
         If InStr(StrName, "mywebaddress.aspx") Then
         Set oie = oapp.Windows(i)
         Exit For
         End If
         Next
         oie.Document.all("ctl11_repeaterNavigator_ctl32_menuLink").Click
```

but the link number changes depending on the users credentials - with my credentials _ctl32 can be _ctl32 or _ctl33 on others. is there a way to search for the inner text and store the link ID as a string?

```
I know I can click on the link by using:
For i = 1 To oie.Document.all.Length
 If oie.Document.all.Item(i).innerText = "Letters" Then
 oie.Document.all.Item(i).Click
 Exit For
End If
Next i
```

but I need the link id store in a string for the next step

Comment: There is an `innerHTML` and `innerText` property for each element in the `oie.Document` Do you know the `TagName` of the menu link? Or the `Name`?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this, assuming the link's `Name` is "Letters" and also assuming that the the prefix "ctl11_repeaterNavigator_" and suffice "_menuLink" will not change for the users.

```
Dim ele as Variant
Dim parseString as String

'## Determine what ctl to use:'

For each ele in oie.Document.GetElementsByName("Letters") '## Modify to use the Name associated with this menu link '
    If Right(ele.InnerHTML,9) = "_menuLink" AND _
        Left(ele.InnerHTML, 24) = "ctl11_repeaterNavigator_" Then 
        ele.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

May have to use `ele.InnerText` instead of `.InnerHTML` so if the above doesn't work, try tweaking it a bit.